# How can I create an algorithm that appends a name onto an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, algorithm

I've been going through Glassdoors for companies I am interested in interviewing with and saw one that said the company asked them a question about "appending a name onto a list". I have been trying to figure out how to go about that. I know the function will take an array and will return an array as well. Can someone help me write that out and explain it to me? Attached is my version, which does not work. It just prints out the existing string twice

```
func addNameToList(_ names: [String]) -> [String] {
    var names = ["Ben", "Sam", "Ken"]
    var results = [names[0]]
    for name in names {
        names.append(name)
        print(names)
    }
    return results
}
addNameToList([String("Louis")])
```

Comment: you probably meant `var names = ["Ben", "Sam", "Ken"]`. Note also that `names` will overshadow the names object passed to your method

Comment: func addNameToList(_ names: [String]) -> [String] {
    var results = []()
    for name in names {
        results.append(name)
        print(name)
    }
    return results
}

Comment: @ElTomato why not simply `return ["Ben", "Sam", "Ken"] + names` ?

Comment: @swiftyswift,pls give sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

if you are need to add one or more string value with Existing string array you can use like below

```
var globalArrayString = ["One","two","three"]
        
func appendString(_ currentString: String...) -> [String] {
    globalArrayString.append(contentsOf: currentString)
    return globalArrayString
}
        
// if you need to add more String,Call like below
        
let combinedArray = appendString("four","five")
print(combinedArray)
```

Comment: @swiftyswift Check and let me know

Comment: You can replace the loop with a simple `append(contentsOf:)`, or `+=`.